# antd design import Import.Search issue

Tags: reactjs, antd

I followed the Input.Search example here https://ant.design/components/input/

```
import { Input } from 'antd';
const Search = Input.Search;

ReactDOM.render(
   <Search placeholder="input search text" onSearch={value => console.log(value)} />
, mountNode);
```

I got the following error:

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Any idea why?

It works just fine if I used the `<Input .../>` component. Why does `<Input.Search .../>` break?

Comment: It works good for me... http://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/jVgWWm?editors=1010. Still having the problem?

Comment: Turned out to be a version problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input.Search` is imported after `antd@2.5.0`, see: https://ant.design/changelog#2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

To import Search from ant design Input your code is wrong.

The correct syntax to Import Search is Given below:-

const {Search} = Input;